# HTML form to POST data to MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to post data to an MySQL database by using Node.js.

This is my htmlHTML form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is my form</h1>
<!-- local host to be changed?  -->
<form action="http://localhost:3000/index.html" method="POST">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `MySQL.js`:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'mysqlhost',
      port     : '3306',
      user     : 'myuser',
      password : 'mypassword',
      database : 'myuser'
    } ); connection.connect(); var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM http://localhost:3000/index.html');

query.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err; });

query.on('fields', function(fields) {
    console.log(fields); })

query.on('result', function(row) {
    console.log(row); }); connection.end();
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM http://localhost:3000/index.html`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but you're definitely not going into the right direction. I suggest learning how to make a simple REST API Node app to get started. This [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) is a good starting point. I suggest using Express as it simplifies the task of handling POST/GET requests.

Here is starter code that does what you want.

### index.html

Note how I used `/data` instead of `localhost:3000/index.html` in the `<form action=...>` part. This is generally known as a REST api.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is my form</h1>
<!-- local host to be changed?  -->
<form action="/data" method="POST">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Doe">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/data', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.firstname);
    console.log(req.body.lastname);
    // Add these values to your MySQL database here
});

app.listen(3000);
```

### File structure

```
app.js
index.html
```

### Commands to run

```
npm install express
npm install body-parser
node app.js
```

Then simply go to `localhost:3000` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks Keith! Will have a look at tutorial and learn more about express.